# (Alexa) Bespoken throws an `cannot find module` when testing locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Hope you all had a wonderful holiday. My name is James David Bohrman and I am currently undertaking my first big code project that is not attached to a tutorial, so I'm exiting a huge stage in my journey.

My project is an Alexa skill that calls on the Cannabis Reports API by using an API wrapper called the same. The goal is to have a skill that accesses the API using the wrapper and creates a voice skill, but I'm having trouble with the Lambda.

Now I will state that I was testing in the Lambda console and not locally, which someone suggested I acquire tools to do.

As I said this is my first solo project so while I do not want my hand held, it is very important to my confidence that I finish this.

One of the errors I'm throwing in Bespoken CLI is  `"Cannot find module 'alexa-sdk'"`

I have my package.json up to date on all my local versions of the project, even those not on GitHub, and `alexa-sdk` is for sure installed.

The github page is a little messy, but it's at https://github.com/jdbohrman/cannabis-reports-alexa

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
var CannabisReport = require('cannabis-report');

const SKILL_NAME = 'Cannabis Report';

const answer = {
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak(HELP_MESSAGE).listen(HELP_REPROMPT);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
     'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
    this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
         this.emit(':responseReady');
     },
     'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
         this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
         this.emit(':responseReady');
      },
     'CannabisReport': function () {
         var speechOutput = Strain.search('');
         this.emit ('tell', speechOutput);
      }
  };

  exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.appId = APP_ID;
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
  });
```

Comment: So you are positive that you have a folder `lambda/custom/node_modules/alexa-sdk/`?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I'll post a screenshot. I noticed that some of the folders have a lock icon and some don't, not sure why. 


 https://imgur.com/fQDCmAg

Comment: Did you edit something inside of the module's folder? I noticed that it was edited Tuesday, whereas the others were last modified 'yesterday'. Have you tried to run the file `index.js` directly from node? Does that produce any errors?